# Get value from key in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array in PHP:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => category
            [value] => OUT
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name_Fr
            [value] => p
        )
...
```

How can I get the value if I know the name ?

I tried:

```
$value = $array['name']['Name_Fr'];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running PHP 5.5, you can do a lot with [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), such as:

```
$newArray = array_column($oldArray, 'value', 'name');
$value = $newArray[$knownName];
```

or even (using array dereferencing):

```
$value = array_column($oldArray, 'value', 'name')[$knownName];
```

For earlier versions of PHP, you could do something like:

```
$value = array_filter(
    $oldArray, 
    function ($value) use ($knownName) { 
        return $value['name'] == $knownName; 
    }
);
$value = array_shift($value);
echo $value['value'], PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to loop through all indexes finding where the names match.

Answer (score 1):

since it's an array of arrays, a loop would help you do so.

```
foreach($arrays as $array)
{
  $value = $array[value]
}
```